# Customized method error in record linkage

Tags: python, function, record-linkage

I want to apply a customized method in the record linkage following the official [documentation](https://recordlinkage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref-compare.html#user-defined-algorithms). My code:

```
import recordlinkage as rl
from recordlinkage.base import BaseCompareFeature



   def compute_wmd( s1, s2):

       word2vec_file = "C:\\Users\\users\\Desktop\\GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin"
       word2vec = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(word2vec_file, binary=True)           
       word2vec.init_sims(replace=True)  # Normalizes the vectors in the word2vec class
       score = word2vec.wmdistance(s1, s2)

       return score


comparer = rl.Compare()

comparer.add(compute_wmd('Description US', 'Description US', label='Description'))
comparer.compute(pairs, csv)
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: compute_wmd() got an unexpected keyword argument 'label'

and if I delete the label I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'labels_left'

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a custom class which inherits the "BaseCompareFeature" and then add a method to the Class named _compute_vectorized(self, s1, s2). Only then Record Linkage will accept it as a valid custom function

Example code:

import recordlinkage as rl
from recordlinkage.base import BaseCompareFeature

class CompareZipCodes(BaseCompareFeature):

```
def __init__(self, left_on, right_on, partial_sim_value, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CompareZipCodes, self).__init__(left_on, right_on, *args, **kwargs)

    self.partial_sim_value = partial_sim_value

def _compute_vectorized(self, s1, s2):
    """Compare zipcodes.

    If the zipcodes in both records are identical, the similarity
    is 0. If the first two values agree and the last two don't, then
    the similarity is 0.5. Otherwise, the similarity is 0.
    """

    # check if the zipcode are identical (return 1 or 0)
    sim = (s1 == s2).astype(float)

    # check the first 2 numbers of the distinct comparisons
    sim[(sim == 0) & (s1.str[0:2] == s2.str[0:2])] = self.partial_sim_value

    return sim
```